# Hovering all images on a td?

Tags: css, html

I want to hover all images on a `td` or on a `table`. I found a way that is came very tiring to me. The way is : I classed all of the images one by one and `CSS'ed` them with hover.

But i want a shortway instead of this. I want to group the pictures and hover them. This could be all images on a td or a table. How can i do this?

Tried `<div>` the `td` but it didn't work. Thanks for help.

Comment: can you add your code, or set up a fiddle?

Comment: use css selectors???? table td img:hover {}

Comment: By the way, i found a solution for my problem. Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. By using `>` after `td` in your css, it will apply the style to only those `img` which are direct child of that `td`. If they are not a direct child then you can remover `>`.

```css
td>img{
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
}
td>img:hover{
  opacity:0.2;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="hoverOver"><img src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg"></td>
  <td class="hoverOver"><img src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg"></td>
  <td class="hoverOver"><img src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg"></td>
  <td class="hoverOver"><img src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks kittyCat for your effort. I think there's no way outside of seperating and invidualizing images for hovering them one by one. While i mouseover one of them, i don't want to show up hovered all four of them. So this is the only solution i think.

Comment: Not in the CSS but there may be a very short javascript solution. If you want to use that I can do that. let me know.

Comment: Thank you.  I want study some Jscript but i do not know when i should start to doing it. I did not even complete the one month process on my HTML5/CSS road (which is two or three weeks since i started to learn them). If you do not think it is not that early you can share me some of your JS knowledges by the way.